# Java's [Input|Output]Streams' one-method-call-for-each-byte: a performance problem?

Tags: java, io, stream, writer

**[Input|Output]Streams** exist since JDK1.0, while their character-counterparts **Readers|Writers** exist since JDK1.1.

Most concepts seem similar, with one exception: the base classes of **streams** declare an abstract method which processes one **single** byte at a time, while base **readers/writers** classes declare an abstract method which processes whole `char`-arrays.

Thus, given that I understand it correctly, every overridden **stream** class is limited to process single bytes (thereby performing at least one method call for **each** byte!), while overridden **readers/writers** only need a method call per array(-buffer).

Isn't that a huge performance problem?

Can a stream be implemented as subclass of either `InputStream` or `OutputStream`, but nevertheless be based on `byte`-arrays?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, subclasses of InputStream have to override the method that reads a single byte at a time, but also can override others methods that read while byte-arrays. I think that's actually the case for most of the Input/Output streams.

So this isn't much of a performance problem, in my opinion, and yes, you can extend Input/Output stream and be based on byte-arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Single byte reading is almost always a huge performance problem. But if you read the API docs of InputStream, you see that you HAVE TO override read(), but SHOULD also override read(byte[],int,int).  Most code that uses any kind of InputStream calls the array style method anyway, but the default implementation of that function is just implemented by calling read() for every byte, so the negative performance impact.

For OutputStream the same holds.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel said, you must override `read()`, since client might use it directly, but you also should override `read (byte[],int,int)`.

However, I doubt if you should be concerned with performance since the jvm can and will inline that method for you. Most of all, it doesn't seem like an issue to me.

Also, most readers use some underlying input stream behind the scene, so in any case those char-array based methods end up calling `read(byte[],int,int)` or even `read()` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `Readers`/`Writers` are for reading characters which can be made of **more** than one byte such as unicode characters. Streams on the other hand are more suitable when you're dealing with non-string (binary) data.

Apart from that, `InputStream` and `OutputStream` also have methods to read/write an entire array of bytes.

Comment: I know, I was talking about **abstract** methods. But now, you and other answerers made clear, that other methods are also suited to be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

performance wise, if you wrap it with BufferedInputStream, JVM should be able to optimize the overhead of single byte read method calls to nothing, i.e. it's as fast as if you do the buffering yourself.